# Creating a YouTube channel api on desktop

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

i did some app for upload video in youtube channel, and some user do not have channel so i need create channel by using api, i did some research and understand that we automatic can create channel only with redirect user on this page

> https://m.youtube.com/create_channel?chromeless=1&next=/channel_creation_done

and after it will redirect to this page

> https://m.youtube.com/channel_creation_done

Take info from here https://developers.google.com/youtube/create-channel

But how i can detect redirect from this page /create_channel to this /channel_creation_done if i use javascript on frond-end ???

Comment: you will be getting status_code as '302' for redirects

Comment: where i will get, from window.open obj?